# jQuery Cycle - change cycle options on click

Tags: jquery-cycle

I want to have a horizontal fx for my third slide, the slider is in fade fx. the third slide is loaded with a simple button not with pager or 'next' 'prev'.
I'm using maximage, so the fx need to be in css too.

So far I achieve to do that:
on click, I change my css, on click I can load my slide.

```
$('.link_contact').click(function() {
$( ".mc-image" ).css( "transition", "left 2s ease !important" );
$( ".mc-image" ).css( "-moz-transition", "left 2s ease !important" );
$( ".mc-image" ).css( "-o-transition", "left 2s ease !important" );
$( ".mc-image" ).css( "-webkit-transition", "left 2s ease !important" );

$('#nav li:eq(2) a').triggerHandler('click');
        return false;
    });
```

now I need to change the cycle option, but I do'nt know how..?
I tried to add

```
$("#maximage").cycle ('fx' , 'scrollHorz');
```

But this is no luck..
does anyonne know what to write instead of to change a cycle option..?

```
$("#maximage").cycle ('fx' , 'scrollHorz');
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cycling element is $("#maximage"), try this:

```
changedOpts = $("#maximage").data('cycle.opts');
changedOpts.fx = 'scrollHorz';
$("#maximage").data('cycle.opts', changedOpts);
```